# Max/Min flow of a network

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, network-flow

I have a network:

[image]
How do I figure out the maximum and minimum possible flow through each undefined branch?

Comment: Do you know how to distinguish if the flow labeled on a graph is a valid flow, given the capacities?

Comment: i'm assuming as long as all undefined branches are less than the output. so in this case if f1+f2+f3 <= 90?

Comment: Define:
A = [1 1 0; 0 -1 1; 1 0 1]
x = [f1; f2; f3]
b = [80; 10; 90]

A*x = b
f1, f2, f3 >= 0 (i guess)

Subject to these equations, LP solve:
- minimums: min(f1), min(f2), min(f3)
- maximums: max(f1), max(f2), max(f3)

Comment: One thing that needs to be clarified, does the blue text represent flow, or does it represent capacities (with unlabeled capacities being infinite)?

Comment: they're representative of flow @DanielV

Comment: Does my comment answer your question?

Comment: I understand putting the equation in terms of Ax=b in order to solve the system, but nothing past that @AdolAurion

Comment: Since this is a linear-programming problem you have to solve a minimum or maximum. In this case you have to solve 6 LP problems: min(f1), min(f2), min(f3), max(f1), max(f2), max(f3). This problem have to be subject to some equations, in this case: A*x = b and f1,f2,f3 >= 0. See more in [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: @AdolOrion I would do this way also. What about Ford-Fulkerson in such a case (old remembrance that need to be refreshed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow must meet the following criteria:

- Flow into a vertex must equal flow out
- Flow must be non-negative
- Flow must be less than or equal to capacity for each edge

For this, we'll have to assume the capacities are "$\infty$".

Vertex $A$ limits the flow of $f_1$ to 80, vertex $C$ limits it to 90.  So we check if there is a flow through $f_1$ of 80:  $f_1 = 80, f_2 = 0, f_3 = 10$ is a valid flow.  We can also check if $0$ is a valid minimum: $f_1 = 0, f_2 = 80, f_3 = 90$.

Proceed similarly for $f_2$ and $f_3$.  Just check "is there a valid flow with $f_n = x$?", you should be able to guess $x$ from the picture.